# Help understanding $\vec{A}_{above}=\vec{A}_{below}$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential, vectors

> Given: a surface with surface charge density $\vec{K}$, $\nabla \cdot A = 0$, $B_{above}-B_{below} = \mu_0 (\vec{K} \times \hat n)$, and $A_{above}=A_{below}$.
>
> What I'm confused about: Because $\vec{A}_{above}=\vec{A}_{below}$ at every point on the surface, it follows that $\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial y}$ are the same above and below; any discontinuity is confined to the normal derivative.

I don't understand this statement. I have a few questions:

1. I interpret the electric potential as the energy a positive charge *could* have if it were placed at a given point. Is it the same thing with the magnetic vector potential?
2. What does it mean to say that "$\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial y}$ are the same above and below"? Does that mean that if I look at a particular point below the surface, then find the derivative with respect to $x$, that this value should be equal in magnitude and direction to the mirror image point *above* the surface?

Comment: Unless you specify the geometry, $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$ are completely meaningless symbols.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty it doesn't specify a surface. I'd assume a generic rectangular one